# Sequelize bulk create adding null to auto-increment primary key

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize to bulk insert data to `ProjectCategory` model. It is trying to insert null every time to the primary key. e.g.

```
          ProjectCategory.bulkCreate(
            projectCategoryIds?.map(categoryId => ({ categoryId, projectId: newProject.id })),
            {
              returning: true,
              transaction: t
            }
          )
```

This gives the following error `null value in column "id" of relation "project_categories" violates not-null constraint`.
Underneath I am using `postgresql@14`.
The method containing this bulk create operation is written like this within a controller:

```
async (req, res) => {
    const { headline, duration, description, attachments, budget, budgetType, budgetCurrency, projectCategoryIds, projectTagIds = [] } = req.body
    let newProject;


    try {
      const user = getUser(req);

      await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
        newProject = await Project.create({ headline, description, duration, attachments, budget, budgetType, budgetCurrency, postedByUserId: user.id }, { transaction: t });

        await Promise.all([
          ProjectCategory.bulkCreate(
            projectCategoryIds?.map(categoryId => ({ categoryId, projectId: newProject.id })),
            {
              returning: true,
              transaction: t
            }
          ),
          ProjectTag.bulkCreate(projectTagIds?.map(tagId => ({ tagId, projectId: newProject.id })), {
            returning: true,
            transaction: t
          })
        ]).then((success) => {
          console.log('asdasda--------------', success)
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log('errrrooro', err)
          throw err;
        })

      })

      return res.status(201).send({ message: 'created', project: newProject })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Create error', err.message);
      if (err instanceof UnauthorizedError) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: showError(err) });
      }
      return res.status(400).send({ message: showError(err) });
    }
  }
```

Here is my `ProjectCategory` model:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class ProjectCategory extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      ProjectCategory.belongsTo(models['Project'], { foreignKey: 'project_id', as: 'project' });
      ProjectCategory.belongsTo(models['Category'], { foreignKey: 'category_id', as: 'category' });
    }
  }
  ProjectCategory.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,

    },
    projectId: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'project_id',
      references: {
        model: 'Project',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    categoryId: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'category_id',
      references: {
        model: 'Category',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'ProjectCategory',
    underscored: true,
    name: 'ProjectCategory',
    timestamps: false
  });

  ProjectCategory.beforeCreate(async (projectCategory, options) => {
    delete projectCategory['id'];
  })

  return ProjectCategory;
};
```

The create migration is as follows:

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('project_categories', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT
      },
      projectId: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'project_id',
        references: {
          model: 'projects',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      categoryId: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'category_id',
        references: {
          model: 'categories',
          key: 'id'
        }
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('project_categories');
  }
};
```

I have tried removing `allowNull: false`, but no luck. This is the query I can see being executed:
`INSERT INTO "project_categories" ("id","project_id","category_id") VALUES (NULL,'31',29) RETURNING "id","project_id","category_id"`

Comment: Check what actual SQL statements this ends up sending to the db. My bet is that one of your helper functions ends up trying to save the object after linking it, before letting it properly initialise first.

Comment: Yeah I aleady checked that, generallyin all `Model.create` sequelize insert some value in primary key but in this case it is passing `null` to id

Comment: Please add relevant updates as edits - it will be useful to see the exact query this generated. I also wouldn't try to guess if it said you checked it :) Have you tried to temporarily disable the `associate` function and/or that `beforeCreate`? It could be a step towards locating the context where this kicks in

Comment: Just tried what you said, those didn't work. I have also updated the exact query in the question. @Zegarek